# using onmouseover as

Tags: javascript, html, image, onmouseover, alternating

I have a continuous loop of alternating images that I would like to be able to interrupt and have display a new picture that corresponds with the current displayed picture using an onmouseover affect for as long as the mouse is on the image.

As an example to better describe my problem, I would like to have a bunch of images alternating on the screen every five seconds (which I can already do). Then when the mouseover event happens, have the images stop alternating and have a new image displayed that corresponds with the image that was just displayed (it will be another image that describes the image that was just being displayed). I also want the images to stop alternating while the mouse is over the images.

So far I can get the first image to display its corresponding image, but I can't seem to get the rest to work. Also I can't get the alternating images to stop while the mouse is still on the image.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<body>

    <img src="image1.jpeg" alt="Image1" width="344" height="311" id="rotator" onmouseover="this.src='imageText1.jpeg'" onmouseout="this.src='image1.jpeg'">



    <script type="text/javascript">
     (function()  {
        var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
        var imageDir = '';
        var delayInSeconds = 5;

        var images = ["image2.png", "image3.gif", "image4.png", "image5.jpeg","image6.gif", "image7.jpeg", "image1.jpeg"];

        var num = 0;
        if (rotator.onmouseover ==  )
        var changeImage = function()  {
            var len = images.length;
            rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
            if (num == len)  {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rotator.onmouseover ==  )
{

}
```

we must check something in if conditon.
empty condition is a problem.please check it.